# Overwriting file when redirecting output from while loop

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I am using multiple subprocessed while loops in a bash script like this at first :

```
while true
do
    echo 'blabla' > /tmp/somefile
    sleep 1
done &
```

but this seem to consume too much write/close operations. So I tried this :

```
while true
do
    echo 'blabla'
    sleep 1
done > /tmp/somefile &
```

but at this point the file is never overwritten, and I would like it to be overwritten each loop.

I tried to integrate a '> /tmp/somefile' inside the loop but file is filled strangely with ^@ character, so it never seems really truncated...

Is there nicer a solution? I thought about file descriptor, but I may have same issues right ?

Comment: If you want the file to be overwritten once per iteration of the loop, then you need to use the first one. If you want to write the output of all iterations to the file, use the second one. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking, could you clarify?

Comment: Don't mistake I/O redirection for full I/O support. You need a way to reposition the file pointer in the second case, and `bash` simply doesn't provide that.

Comment: @Tom Fenech I am trying to reduce file open/write/close operations.

Comment: Like @chepner said, use a "complete" programming language and reposition the pointer.  Can`t do it in bash.

Comment: You could write and enable your own `bash` built-in command to provide a seek. Cf. the `sysseek` command that Z shell can use via the `zsh/system` module.

Comment: When you really have a `sleep 1`, the i/o in the first solution should be moderate. With a higher rate, reconsider why you need so many short-lived tmp files. Is it used for inter-process communication?